# Running curl locally vs inside an erb file yields different results

Tags: ruby, puppet, erb

I have a template file which I'd like to execute some simple code in (I have an endpoint which returns some json revealing other server details which are relevant to the template). I've added in the following code (values omitted where relevant):

```
<% require 'open3'
url = 'https://a.valid.address.com'
path = '/nodeStatuses'
port = '18091'
username = 'admin'
password = "#{@template_password}"


Open3.popen3("curl -m 10 -X GET --noproxy '*' -vvvv -m 10 --cacert /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/RootCA.crt -k -u #{username}:#{password} #{url}:#{port}#{path}") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
  pid = thread.pid
  stdin.close
  @stdout = stdout.read.chomp
  @stderr = stderr.read.chomp
end  %>

stdout: <%= @stdout %>
stderr: <%= @stderr %>
```

Strangely all my templates are filled with timeouts:

```
stderr:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to a.valid.address.com port 18091 (#0)
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--     0^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0* Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
```

My immediate thoughts were that the url is offline or there's something wrong with the curl, but running the same command via command line yields results:

```
curl -I -s -m 10 --cacert /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/RootCA.crt -k -u admin:secret https://a.valid.address.com:18091/nodeStatuses
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: Couchbase Server
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Fri, 30 Sep 2022 09:00:46 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 685
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
```

Then I thought it might be a limitation with erb; nope I get a response from another url (e.g stackoverflow).

Really looking for some clues here. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Requiring a gem, running a shell command in a thread which executes a HTTP request while capturing stdout and stderr is a level of complexity I would not put inside a template ;-)

Comment: @Stefan is there a better way of achieving the same result? This is just an idea I’ve had in my head which I’m testing.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, but i would rather run it outside the template and just pass the result(s) into the template. Probably also makes it easier to narrow down the problem. (it's most likely not an ERB issue)

Comment: Could I have a seperate ruby function to do this and then call the function from within the template or will I just get the same issue?

Comment: That's the same. Did you try running your code in Ruby, i.e. on the same machine but outside of ERB / Puppet?

Comment: I think I know the problem… are templates rendered on puppet masters? I can curl locally but the puppetmaster isn’t able to. If I run tcpdump on the puppetmaster I can see connection attempts to my port (18091) which is firewalled. I need this to execute locally and instead it’s executing on the puppetmaster.

Comment: Running crucial code as a side effect of rendering a template seems quite brittle. I don't know puppet but there's probably a way to have code outside of ERB.

Comment: Yes, @keeer, the template is evaluated on the master, during catalog compilation.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger is there a way around this other than using the deferred method (I'm using puppet5 which doesn't have support).

Comment: If it makes sense to do so, you can run your code in a custom fact.  If you can make it work for you, you can run it via an `Exec`.  Or you can always create a custom type and provider.

Comment: The facts would need things only available after the puppet run though (things like a server name to query, a username and password stored in eyaml). My experience with custom facts is they aren’t exactly dynamic. Ideally I’d want a fact which takes a couple of variables (host to query and password for instance) and forms a new fact name (based on the variable name) with a value specific to the server running it. Complicated…

Comment: Well then, @keeer, it sounds like one of the other two options would be better suited.  It sounds like a custom type is really what you should go for, but perhaps you could shortcut with the help of `Exec` and other resources, maybe wrapped up in a defined type.

Comment: The exec would need to store the output though (I assume as a variable to populate a template), that’s not something which is possible to the best of my knowledge? I assume you can’t run exec statements inside an erb? The other options sound a little complicated for my use case. Thanks for your help by the way, you’ve helped me lots in the past :-).

Comment: No.  The `Exec` alternative would want to be structured quite differently, so that it generated the wanted file directly instead of (only) generating data to feed into a template.

Comment: I see, so the exec generates a template; thanks. I actually switched this around a lot and used resources available on the puppetmaster in the end and made this template run in a similar way. In this instance I used bolt to return a list of hosts (rather than curl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This template was being rendered on the puppetmaster and not locally on the server (this is expected behaviour). In the end I changed the logic and made the command executed on the puppetmaster return a list of hosts to populate the template file. This isn’t quite what I’d intended to do originally, but the end result is the same/similar.